# how to access the internal file of APK with Unity c# file?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm developing a mobile application using Unity. The project works well when I implement it in PC,  but as soon as I build it in APK and I implement it, That application is terminated immediately. I guess the problem is in .txt file. In mobile, .txt. file's path'll be changed. I don't know how to access the internal file of APK with Unity c# code. I just want to read file. Thank you for your help!

now, I'm using "TextAsset" as a variable and then It matches with my .txt file in Unity Editor.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question you have serialized a file in the path and when you trying to open error appears . So use Application.persistentdatapath + filename when you are creating or opening file .This will save in windows appdata locallow in android under installed folder. Hope i helped you